# Regex match a hash that has been split over multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a hash that has been word wrapped by an author, and received over multiple lines.

Example:
  SHA256: AB76235776BC87DBAB76235776BC87DBAB76235776BC87
  DBAB76235776BC87DB

Has been received.  My usual regex to match a sha256 hash like this is of course: [0-9A-Fa-f]{64}

But this does not work.  I would like to leave the file unmodified while searching for this match, any ideas on how to match the split hash without removing newlines?

I'd like to have a regex that basically says 'look for 64 sequential hexadecimal values, but allow for one or more newlines in the mix, kthx'

Thanks in advance. C# is the language.

Comment: Why not add newline characters to the characterclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(?:[a-fA-F0-9]\s*){64}\b
```

It allows any kind of whitespace, not just line separators.  If it really has to allow only line separators, you can use this:

```
\b(?:[a-fA-F0-9][\r\n]*){64}\b
```

This will also include the line separator following the number, if there is one, and if it's followed by a word character.  You can prevent that like this:

```
\b(?:[a-fA-F0-9][\r\n]*){63}[a-fA-F0-9]\b
```

Comment: Fantastic! You're a regex wizard!

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to include newline characters:

```
[A-Z0-9a-z\\r\\n ]{64, }
```

You could modify the upper bound to include a restriction on the number of linebreaks.
In this case you need to keep in mind linebreaks can be 2 symbols long, depending on machine culture and OS.

> 1 linebreak --> 66 chars
>   2 linebreaks --> 68  chars
>   Continue as much as you like.

On a sidenote. While parsing the file, you generally leave it rest. All your modifications are made with the variables you read the file in to. This is why I do not see the point of keeping the linebreaks.

Comment: True, but then would it not also match 65 (or 66) sequential hexadecimal digits?

Comment: Yep. But if you don't want to remove line reaks that is the only way, given you are only allowed to use regex of course you could just kick out [\r\n] with a single command beforehand but hey...

Comment: Is there a way to ignore line breaks? Basically have the regex not care if there is a new line in between?